# EOS blockchain explorer

Tags: blockchains

Where i can check if my EOS created account is successfully created or not?

is there something similar website like `etherscan.io` for EOS?

i spent few hours but could not find anything useful

Comment: you can just query a bp using the http API to check for your account

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what block explorer is updated in real time, but if you want to check your account, you can just type this in the terminal:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.eosnewyork.io/v1/chain/get_account \
  --data '{"account_name":"YOUR_ACCOUNT"}'
```

In regards to block explorers, the ones listed on [r/eos](https://reddit.com/r/eos) are:

- [EOS Tracker](https://eostracker.io/)
- [EOSPark](https://eospark.com/)
- [eosflare](https://eosflare.io/)
- [EOSQuery](https://eosquery.com/)

Comment: thanks for reply, i tried `curl --request POST  --url https://api.eosnewyork.io/v1/chain/get_account  --data '{"account_name":"mytestacct"}'` but there is an error returned `{"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":0,"name":"exception","what":"unspecified","details":[{"message":"unknown key","file":"http_plugin.cpp","line_number":478,"method":"handle_exception"}]}}` But when i run this command ` ./cleos get account mytestacct --json` it works. I just want to to test if my account is successfully registered in blockchain or not?

Comment: i have read somewhere that while creating account, we have to pay something for CPU, RAM etc? But how can i get EOS balance in fresh node? I'm able to create account with this command `./cleos create account eosio tstaccnt Publickey Publickey` does it directly creates my account on blockchain? or in my node only?

Comment: If you're using `cleos create account`, then you're on a testnet with `eosio.system` not deployed yet. Once you deploy `eosio.system`, you'll create accounts with `cleos system newaccount` and you'll have to delegate tokens for bandwidth. However, you'll still be connected to local net, and not to the mainnet. You need to provide the appropriate mainnet `genesis.json` for that but it's a whole different issue that perhaps we shouldn't expand too much in the comments of this question

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple get account and see if your newly created account comes up:

```
cleos get account <YOURACCOUNT>
```

Regarding explorers, I quite like [bloks.io](https://bloks.io)